# Add Button value to html form submission which is outside the form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

How to include the "two" in params submitted to the server using only JQuery?

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <inout type="text" name="one" value="ten"/>
</form>
  <button name="two" id="form_submit" value="twenty" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#form_submit").click(function(){
   $("#myForm").submit();
 });
```

I want to send the button params to the server along with the rest of the form params by using only JQuery and without changing above html code?

Comment: use input type hidden inside form  and see that the button parameters are added to it

Comment: why it is outside form..just curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a hidden input to the form before submission:

```
$("#form_submit").click(function() {
    var $h = $('<input/>', { type: 'hidden', name: 'submitted_by', value: this.name});
    $("#myForm").append($h).submit();
});
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, like the attribute collection. `:)` @undefined